# Installing xlsx to process excel sheet to json

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, npm, aws-sdk

Below is the command I ran to install xlsx :

```
sudo npm install xlsx
npm install xlsx
sudo npm install excel --save-dev
npm install excel --save-dev
```

After each of these I get a similar error :

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "excel" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /home/<User>/customer_service/node_modules/aws-sdk
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall rename
```

and a big list of errors which involve rename and deletion of a few files like aws-sdk.
Note :

1. I have aws-sdk installed. After each of those above commands aws-sdk would be renamed/deleted automatically. So I had to install aws-sdk every time I ran the above files.
2. I have NOT uninstalled xlsx after each of those commands.Should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution:
Use sudo along with global and save it. If using aws-sdk, then create a different directory to avoid overwriting as aws-sdk has its own node-modules.